# How to populate ComboBoxTableCell Dropdown list

Tags: java, javafx

I have a cellFactory which creates editable ComboBoxTableCell in TableView columns:

```
Callback<TableColumn<Map, String>, TableCell<Map, String>>
            cellFactoryForComboBox = (TableColumn<Map, String> p) -> {
                ComboBoxTableCell<Map, String> cell = new ComboBoxTableCell<>();
                cell.setComboBoxEditable(true);
                return cell;
        };

Col1.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForComboBox);
Col2.setCellFactory(cellFactoryForComboBox);
```

How can I populate dropDown lists for each column with values in

```
ObservableList<String> List1
ObservableList<String> List2
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Create seperate `cellFactory`s for each column and pass the `ObservableList` to [the constructor of `ComboBoxTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html#ComboBoxTableCell-javafx.collections.ObservableList-):

```
Col1.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Map, String> p) -> {
                ComboBoxTableCell<Map, String> cell = new ComboBoxTableCell<>(List1);
                cell.setComboBoxEditable(true);
                return cell;
        });
Col2.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Map, String> p) -> {
                ComboBoxTableCell<Map, String> cell = new ComboBoxTableCell<>(List2);
                cell.setComboBoxEditable(true);
                return cell;
        });
```